# How do you read "tr"?

Tags: pronunciation

I've got this little doubt over the pronunciation of "tr" in words (trial, attraction,  actress). I recognized two ways of reading it - either as ch (like CHoose) + r or as t (as in Ten) + r, which I use interchangeably.
Is one of these pronunciations correct, or are there rules as to which one to use in which situations?